# mat-select-search is not a known element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) to create mat-select. I copied the whole code including the mat-select folder and module. The whole code compiles perfectly without any error or issues. However, during page rendering time the code breaks and I get error `Unexpected directive 'MatSelectSearchComponent' imported by the module 'AngularMaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.` 
In the main HTML page where I am trying to use the mat-select there on mat-select-search tag, I am getting an error that `mat-select-search is not a known element`.
Although the code compiles without any error.

I tried importing mat-select-searchmodule in layout.component.ts then I am getting the below error

```
 Type MatSelectSearchComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MatSelectSearchModule and InsertModule! Please consider moving MatSelectSearchComponent to a higher module that imports MatSelectSearchModule and InsertModule.
```

Comment: The error you are describing here doesn't occur on stackblitz. The stackblitz link is your project or you are just using in some of your projects?

Comment: In stackblitz it works fine.. i am using some the code of that stackblitz in my project

Comment: Please provide here [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.